# enable fanotify on oracle redhat linux kernel 2.6.39-400

Tags: redhat, oracle, linux-kernel, clamav

As a newbie in linux environment, I am trying to install clamav daemon, which is clamd, on oracle redhat linux 6 kernel EUK 2.6.39-400. It needs to have fanotify enabled in the kernel. As I see there is no fanotify.h in the "/usr/include/directory/". I know the stable release of fanotify is in the 3.6.37 and later of linux kernel. I want to enable it in the current release without getting the source code of the kernel and compile it. Although, I did that before and I faced too many errors and problems in compiling source code.

Is there any management like "windows component manager" in linux to make it easier to enable that feature? Or any other way to make it.

Currently I got the source code of kernel 3.2.x on CentOS and kernel 2.6.32.x and I don't have problem in compiling it to make new working kernel based on source code. but in Oracle linux I have many problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why does this question get down-voted? It appears to me as a serious question.

I would recommend that you start over again. As far as I know clamav is not included in the Oracle Linux distribution. You have to add a yum repository which has clamav.

To add a yum repository add a file to the following path which contains the yum repository configuration: `/etc/yum.repos.d/`.

Once you did that you can install clamav with `yum search clamav clamd`. For more information on how to install clamav you might want to look at this blog page: [centosblog.com](https://www.centosblog.com/how-to-install-clamav-and-configure-daily-scanning-on-centos/). CentOS is pretty similar to Oracle Linux. So you can adopt the information.

If you are new to linux you also might want approach the topic on a different path. When I was new to linux I used [webmin](http://webmin.com/community.html) or [virtualmin](https://www.virtualmin.com/download.html) to manage my server. Virtualmin is based on webmin and is optimized for websites, mailservers and DB servers (MySQL and PostgreSQL). Both products have a free and a commercial version.

To install virtualmin you simply install a minimum centos and then use the virtualmin installer script to install all other packages. I never tried to install virtualmin on an Oracle Linux.

I didn't really answer your question but I think this option will bring you closer to you goal.

Comment: I think the problem is to compile the source of the UEK kernel version. For instance I can get any particular version of official Linux source kernel on CentOS and compile it and make the as the running kernel. The problem is we cannot change the kernel version and we need to stick to the same version of kernel. For that reason I got the devel package of the same Linux UEK kernel version and tried to compile it. I guess because the devel package is not complete source of runnig kernel.
Also I used EPEL repository for installing clamav and all its related components.

Answer (score 1):

I have asked Redhat to make all kernel version by default have fanotify enabled. But without a way to control which program can use fanotify, it's dangerous that hacker could use it to hide illegal changes made to the system.

Answer (score 0):

I found an efficient way to prevent a malicious person to do bad things on Linux, including not to install a program that uses the fanotify to hide critical file changes: the one that able to combat software-based key stealing attacks privilege delegation software CaclMgr. And by using the tool in the package, you can make any  admin user account once logged in, all activities will be logged.